# Firebase execute code IF child has been created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, addeventlistener

I have the following code for deleting some data form Firebase:

```
public void removeGameFromWaitQueue() {
        final DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("games").child(mCurrentGameKey);
        data.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    mCurrentGame = snapshot.getValue(DatabaseModels.Game.class);
                    if (mCurrentGame.getState() == DatabaseModels.Game.State.OPEN.ordinal()){
                        data.removeValue();
                }

            }

                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
```

How can i check if "data" exists, then execute all the else code? Meaning that if i create the DatabaseReference, code works. But of course if i dont create the reference, then i have null exceprion. Should i have 2 listeners for this? And if yes, how is the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean through "How can i check if "data" exists"? If your `mCurrentGame` exist? Is this what you want?

Comment: Almost yes as if i didnt have a game created i had null pointer exceprion. But i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference i solved it like this:

```
public void removeGameFromWaitQueue() {

        final DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("games").child(mCurrentGameKey);
        data.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    mCurrentGame = snapshot.getValue(DatabaseModels.Game.class);
                    if (mCurrentGame.getState() == DatabaseModels.Game.State.OPEN.ordinal()){
                        data.removeValue();
                }

            }

                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    }

public void removeAfterCheck(){
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChild("games")) {
               removeGameFromWaitQueue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Probably there is a better way, but this works for me in all cases as i want.

Comment: Please also add an explanation to this answer, not only the code.